# Transform dataset in R

Tags: r, dataset, transform

I tried to transform my data as follows using R.I tried tidyverse but not luck to get into a single column. I have case such as Col2 has upto 50 records for a col1.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `dplyr::group_by()`

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "C"),
  col2 = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6")
)
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% group_by(col1) %>% summarize(col2 = paste(col2, collapse = ",")) %>% ungroup()
```

Now the result is what you expected

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  col1  col2 
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     V1,V2
2 B     V3   
3 C     V4,V6
4 D     V5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate`, but depending on how you want `col2` presented

1. gathered in a `list`

```
> (res <- aggregate(col2 ~ col1, df, c))
  col1   col2
1    A V1, V2
2    B     V3
3    C V4, V6
4    D     V5

> str(res)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ col1: chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"
 $ col2:List of 4
  ..$ : chr  "V1" "V2"
  ..$ : chr "V3"
  ..$ : chr  "V4" "V6"
  ..$ : chr "V5"
```

2. gathered in a `string`

```
> (res <- aggregate(col2 ~ col1, df, toString))
  col1   col2
1    A V1, V2
2    B     V3
3    C V4, V6
4    D     V5

> str(res)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ col1: chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"
 $ col2: chr  "V1, V2" "V3" "V4, V6" "V5"
```